# Sabemos o que fazer com uma pergunta em inglês. E com uma resposta?

Tags: debate

Já é a segunda vez nessa semana que me deparo com uma resposta em inglês. A primeira vez foi uma resposta em inglês para uma pergunta em inglês. Já a segunda vez, foi [nessa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/171266/4995) para uma pergunta escrita em português.

Nós temos a opção de sinalizar uma pergunta que está em inglês para fechamento. Mas, no caso das respostas, não temos essa opção.

O que deveríamos fazer em tais casos?

Comment: Eu creio que nao há necessidade de banir respostas em ingles, se realmente os usuários nao souberem a lingua. Eu editaria a resposta e colocaria uma nota que a resposta foi traduzida. Se por algum motivo for necessário ver a versao original, ela está no histórico de edicao. Mas pode depender do caso...

Comment: @BrunoCosta mas se o usuário não sabe a lingua, a pergunta é fechada da mesma forma se tiver em inglês. Então nesse caso, acho que haveria um tratamento similar pra respostas.

Comment: Depende do ponto de vista. Se calhar a intencao da comunidade é mesmo nao ter nenhum usuário que nao saiba falar portugues (ou que nao use um tradutor). Se for esse o caso excluir a respsota parece-me a única hipótese.

Comment: @BrunoCosta no caso, acho que ou o AR traduz, ou alguém traduz

Comment: Mas isso foi o que eu disse `Eu editaria a resposta e colocaria uma nota que a resposta foi traduzida`

Comment: @BrunoCosta o problema resolve para quem tem uma "confiança" no seu entendimento em um idioma diferente, como o inglês. Todavia a maioria vive de google tradutor, o que causa muitos problemas, ao meu ver traduzir não é uma boa solução. Só irá servir para alguns que tem familiaridade com o idioma, o que são raros os casos.

Comment: meta|duplicado relacionado: [Eu não falo bem Português. Está tudo bem para escrever uma resposta?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/648/91)

Answer (score 11):

Há duas principais possibilidades para abordar o caso:

1. Preferimos respostas em PT, mas lidamos da melhor for possível com respostas em outro idioma.
2. Demandamos respostas em PT e conteúdo em outro idioma deverá ser traduzido ou removido.

Particularmente, não creio que um usuário deva ser punido por tentar ajudar alguém, mesmo em outro idioma. A princípio, a primeira opção parece ser a mais coerente e tolerante.

Por outro lado, devemos pensar na comunidade como um todo. E se fosse um idioma como Mandarim, Árabe ou Grego? Imagine a situação onde o autor da pergunta e o autor da resposta, ambos conhecem um desses idiomas e conseguem se entender, mas às custas do restante da comunidade.

Claro que Inglês é uma língua muito mais comum para programadores e comumente nos deparamos com código escrito nesse idioma. Eu mesmo sou culpado disso algumas vezes, embora me esforce para não fazê-lo.

Portanto, minha sugestão para a comunidade é que seja um pouco tolerantes com respostas em outros idiomas, mas sem deixar que elas permaneçam desta forma.

Como fazer isso?

- Se tiver a disposição, tente traduzir a resposta. É um favor à comunidade.
- Adicione um comentário solicitando a tradução e coloque uma flag para que outros usuários e moderadores estejam atentos.
- Finalmente, se a resposta não for traduzida por uma razão qualquer, talvez seja a hora de votar para excluí-la.

Por enquanto, o volume é tão baixo que acredito haver voluntários o suficiente para lidar com o problema. É importante notar que isto é uma contribuição voluntária. Não se sinta obrigado a fazer traduções de forma alguma.

Se acordarmos um dia e notarmos que o problema está ficando fora de controle, causando algum estresse na comunidade, então caberá atitudes mais duras.

Comment: Utluiz, como você disse, realmente foi a primeira vez que vi isso. Fiz a pergunta no meta mesmo no sentido de saber o que fazer. Eu não sou bom nos inglês, então sinalizar me pareceu mais correto para chamar atenção.